# How to Use ShinyProxy in Production

Tags: r, shiny, shinyproxy

Apologize in advance if this question is general or basic, but I need help in understanding some foundational practices.

**What I have:**

Dockerized shiny apps deployed using `ShinyProxy`, hosted with on `AWS ec2` instance, and linked with `auth0` through ShinyProxy.

**What I want to know**

1. How do I share this one app with my clients without them having to see the main page (and the nav bar)?

Now when I go to my `www.example.com/myapp`, the `auth0` logging-in page pops up, once the user logs-in, it redirects them to the `www.example.com` rather than my app.

2. How should I work with many shiny apps deployed with shiny proxy to several customers in production? Some of these apps will need to have no authentication, some of them need to give access to few users and while the other apps to different users. They all don't need to see the main landing page.

I will really appreciate any theoretical or technical explanations. Thank you!

I tried to find guidance or explinations online but I couldn't find.